# Why does a thrown exception kill all Mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to run a number of selenium tests split across separate files. If selenium throws an exception because it can't find an element, it kills the whole process and Mocha stops and gives me the report. It doesn't run the rest of the tests.

The behaviour I expect is that Mocha would fail that test and continue.

I have tried the Mocha option --allow-uncaught which doesn't appear to help